# Date.UTC() vs strtotime() ?? Why different?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, timestamp, utc

Why am I getting two results when using these functions...

```
<?php
echo strtotime("2011-9-9")."<script type='text/javascript'>alert(Date.UTC(2011, 9, 9)/1000);</script>";
?>
```

this gives me 1315526400 and a js alert of 1318118400.. Why are these so different!?

Also, what is the best way to take a UTC timestamp (integer) and parse it for only the year, month, and day?

Thanks

Comment: Dennis has helped me out with the first part, but I am still needing a way to take a UTC timestamp (integer) and parse it for only the year, month, and day (In PHP)..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Javascript zero indexes its months, so the PHP code refers to september, but JS refers to october.
From the Chrome dev console:

```
new Date(1315526400000)
Thu Sep 08 2011 20:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)
new Date(1318118400000)
Sat Oct 08 2011 20:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)
```

Comment: heh.. wow.. That would solve the problem I am having.. Also, is there a way to directly parse the integer for only the years, months, and day? for both php and javascript?

Comment: Javascript functions are documented [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Methods_2).  The methods you are interested in are `getMonth`, `getFullYear` and `getDate`.  Not sure about PHP though.

Comment: First Google hit for `php date` gives you this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php - The function takes a format and timestamp as input and gives you the interesting information as output.